# Grails addTo* not getting created

Tags: json, grails, groovy

Having trouble with Grails Domain Classes. I am overriding the constructor to build the domain class object from a net.sf.json.JSONObject. This works fine when I insantiate an object via a controller. Then I tried to instantiate it via a test case, and got an exception:

**No signature of method: profileplugin.Contact.addToEmails() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [something@something.com]**

I should also point out that this seems to work with some classes, but not others. Very frustrating -- I'm new to Grails, so if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it very much.

Here's my domain class code.

```
package profileplugin

import net.sf.json.JSONObject

class Contact
{
    static hasMany =
    [
        phones: String,
        faxes: String,
        emails: String,
        websites: String,
    ];

    Contact() {};  // standard constructor must be specified, or grails dies
    Contact(JSONObject source)
    {
        source.get('emails').each()         { this.addToEmails(it);   };
        source.get('websites').each()       { this.addToWebsites(it); };
        source.get('phones').each()         { this.addToPhones(it);   };
        source.get('faxes').each()          { this.addToFaxes(it);    };
    };

}
```

And here's an example source JSON string ...

```
[
    addresses:[], 
    phones:["(555) 555-7011"], 
    faxes:[], 
    emails:["someone@something.com"], 
    websites:["http://www.google.com"]
]
```

And, finally, here's the version of the code that worked (after getting feedback below):

```
class Contact
{
    def phones = [];
    def faxes = [];
    def emails = [];
    def websites = [];

    Contact() {};  // standard constructor must be specified, or grails dies
    Contact(JSONObject source)
    {
        print source;

        source.get('phones').each()         { this.phones.add(it);   };
        source.get('emails').each()         { this.emails.add(it);   };
        source.get('websites').each()       { this.websites.add(it); };
        source.get('faxes').each()          { this.faxes.add(it);    };
    };

}
```

Comment: could you zip a sample project so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your source code, you should not have a `,` at the end of your `websites: String,` I am surprised it did compile.

There is nosense to put hasMany relationship for a String class (unless you want to make database transaction on it then it is better to create domain classes for phones, faxes, emails and websites). You should rewrite this way:

```
package profileplugin

import net.sf.json.JSONObject

class Contact
{

    String[] phones=new String[]
    String[] faxes=new String[]
    String[] emails=new String[]
    String[] websites=new String[]

    ...

}
```

and then use:

```
this.emails.add(it)
```

Also and probably more importantly, you **SHOULD NOT** add business logic inside your domain class, it should be inside your controller, service or in some external classes (under `src` directory).

EDIT:
actually it does not compile properly, the right syntax is:

```
def emails = []
etc...
```

thanks to ben

Comment: In both java and groovy, trailing commas in map, array or list definitions are fine

Comment: "you *SHOULD NOT* add business logic inside your domain class" - IMNSHO that's the false part. Of course, Hibertate interferes with logic in setters, but business logic is *THE* definition of domain classes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, but your example code doesn't compile. The syntax doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: I was able to get a slightly different error by specifying an array size (def phones = new String[100]). The same problem though: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.add() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

Comment: Ok, I've gotten it to work, in part based on your suggestions. Updating post with working code.

Answer (score 2):

Did you define mock object for domain class? [see](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains)